# es module loader for React.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, es6-modules, supabase

I am trying to add `supabase/auth-ui` to my react project

```
https://github.com/supabase/auth-ui
```

My runtime error is:

```
./node_modules/@supabase/auth-ui-react/dist/index.es.js 1095:48
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1095:48)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

I think this means that I cannot handle ES modules.  Do I need a webpack plugin?

Comment: I am facing the same issue and can't find a solution. Where is this tsconfig.json file? I am using javascript though.

Comment: @Akil I think all your config is hidden -- I think you need to eject react  -- npm run eject 
 -- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These `tsconfig.json` values fixed it:

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  },
```